# What to say to reckless teenager in the hallway?

Tags: safety, school

I've been working as an high school "guard" or "watcher" and I often encounter reckless teenager running or wrestling in the hallway.

Off course I could use the good old operant conditioning but it is much better to make them understand basic safety and concussion prevention.

I've been explaining to reckless teenagers that it is more likely to get a concussion from a surface like ceramic or concrete than wood flooring (gymnasium). Despite my low-average knowledge on that.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. If we had the answer(s) here, believe me, we'd be happy to share. But you seem to want to know (what exactly? That's where I'm confused.) If you're looking for injury stats, there's a site called Medical Science.SE. If you want to discuss approaches to discussions with teens, that's on topic, but you're asking (I think?) what sentence(s) will change a teen's behavior quickly in the hall. Unfortunately, that probably won't happen unless you can dispense disciplinary measures, which doesn't sound like the approach you're looking for. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Changing teen behavior requires a lot of one-on-one time, earning their respect (and respecting them) as you go, or a very big stick. They are pretty much by nature trying to become self-determining. Which causes them collectively to do an enormous number of iffy things. Teenagers truly are not adults.

Comment: I agree with @anongoodnurse, but I'll be a bit more blunt: if you're going to work with teens, get used to it. The only cure for teenageritis is time and maturation

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such; question spaces are not the place to edit in an answer. I know you can't answer this question as it is now closed, and I ask you to please respect the structure of this site (questions and answers are separate; answers are full, not link-only. A question and answer on Medical Science.SE is fine.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing 1) they already know they could get hurt doing that; 2) half of them **have been hurt before** from tripping while running, or being shoved into things while wrestling; and 3) they don't care.

Statistics on accidents while running at school might help, if you can find them. Also reminding them they might not be able to play in the big game on Friday (or run in the meet, or whatever) if they get hurt.  And that it's one thing if they get hurt fooling around, but if they accidentally hurt someone else, it will be a big deal.

You still have to say it, just don't be surprised if they don't seem to listen.

True story:  My daughter was running in the hall at school when a teacher spoke to her sharply.  Still running, she looked over her shoulder to acknowledge the teacher and misjudged her distance to the steps in front of her.  She slammed her foot into them, tripped and caught herself, then ran up the stairs.  The teacher rolled her eyes and sighed and went back into the classroom.

We discovered the next day that my daughter had broken her toe.

My daughter still runs in the hallway.